# How to manually start Driving Mode?

Tags: bluetooth, driving-mode

Is there any way to manually trigger Driving Mode in Windows Phone 8.1? Or does it work only when a Bluetooth device gets connected?

I am aware that I can have a Bluetooth device in any car, I'm just curious to know if it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: This is a bizarre condition. When I DON'T have BT in the car to answer calls/texts using voice/steering wheel controls is precisely when I DO want to set driving mode on.

Comment: @Muffy I'm not sure I understand you? The driving mode is all about pairing with your car via bluetooth - or are you trying to use a cable kit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Driving mode [requires](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/use-driving-mode) a bluetooth presense to operate. It cannot be turned on manually, or by any other means at this point.